# difference between index REBUILD and REORGANIZE in relation to recompile in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, index

Does the INDEX **REORGANIZE** index cause recompilation of the stored procs the same way as  INDEX **REBUILD**

Comment: Does an Index rebuild recompile SPs? It's good practice to recompile SPs if new indexes have been added so the SP can choose to use them.

Answer (score 2):

Index reorganize does not touches statistics so there is no chance for causing recompilation. Since when index is rebuilt with full scan stats are also updated for the column this can trigger recompilation as statistics change.